# How to resize/compress or Set default height width / stylesheet classes of Images Upload by django Ckeditor

Tags: python, django, ckeditor, django-ckeditor

I'm Using Django-Ckeditor for RichTextUploadField, However, some images are pretty large and I need to resize/compress before sending it to server [image]

or If i can set default width and height or Stylesheet classes [image]

[image]

I tried this but no luck:

```
CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
'default': {
    'stylesSet': [
        {
            'name': 'Image-Fluid',
            'element': 'img',
            'attributes': {'class': 'img-fluid'},
        },
    ],
},
```

}

Need your help community. Any Idea How to make this possible.
My CKeditor config: [gist](https://gist.github.com/vineetsingh065/b6ec2d9cd4fb16e9ae310df26bdd45e5)